Proving $f_X(x) = a^2 x \exp(-ax)$ with conditional uniform distribution
Problem: Suppose $P(X>0) = 1$ and the conditional distribution of $Y \mid X = x \sim U(0,x)$. Let $Z = X - Y$ and suppose that $Y$ and $Z$ are independent. Prove that $f_X(x) = a^2 x \exp\{-ax\}$, for $x > 0$.
My try: We have that:
$$
\frac{P(Z=z, Y=y)}{P(X=x)} = P(Z=z, Y=y \mid X = x) = P(Z=z \mid X=x) P(Y=y \mid X=x),
$$
then
$$
P(X=x) = \frac{P(X-Y=z, Y=y)}{P(X-Y=z \mid X=x) P(Y=y \mid X=x)} = x \cdot \frac{P(X-Y=z, Y=y)}{P(X-Y=z \mid X=x)}.
$$
But I don't know how to make an $exp\{\cdot\}$ appear.

You probably want to convolve and appeal to fourier transforms.

@Andrew It's not at all obvious to me how it works by Fourier Transformation. Writing X = Z + Y and using that Z and Y are independent I think it works, but I'm having trouble with the integral of the joint distribution.

We also see that $Z|X \sim U(0,X)$. Therefore using moment generating functions:
$$M_X(t):=\mathbb E\left[e^{tX}\right]=\mathbb E\left[e^{t(Y+Z)}\right]=\mathbb E\left[e^{tY}\right]\mathbb E\left[e^{tZ}\right]$$
where the last equality is by independence of $Y$ and $Z$. Using the tower law of conditional expectation and the MGF of the uniform distribution:
$$\mathbb E\left[e^{tY}\right]\mathbb E\left[e^{tZ}\right]=\mathbb E\left[\mathbb E\left[e^{tY}|X\right]\right]\mathbb E\left[\mathbb E\left[e^{tZ}|X\right]\right]=\left( \mathbb E\left[\frac{e^{tX}-1}{tX} \right] \right)^2$$
and so
$$M_X(t)=\frac{1}{t^2}\left( \mathbb E\left[\frac{e^{tX}-1}{X} \right] \right)^2=\frac{1}{t^2}\left( \int_0^t\mathbb E\left[ e^{sX} \right]ds \right)^2=\frac{1}{t^2}\left( \int_0^tM_X(s)ds \right)^2.$$
Let $f'=M_X$, then $f$ satisfies the ODE
$$f'(t)=\frac{f(t)^2}{t^2}.$$
The general solution of this is $$f(t)=\frac{t}{1+\lambda t},$$ which means that
$$M_X(t)=f'(t)=\frac{1}{(1+\lambda t)^2}$$
and you should find that the moment generating functions associated with the probability density functions $f_X(x)=a^2x\exp\{-ax\}$ are the same family of functions (up to some potential difference in parametrisation between $\lambda$ and $a$).

This $M_X(t)$ corresponds to $Gamma(2, \lambda)$ which has the pdf in the form we want. Thanks @Wei.
